# Using PL/SQL (not a simple query) and the theater database: Report the average ticket price for tickets sold to the movie "STATE OF THE UNION.”

Tags: variables, subquery, average

1. Using PL/SQL (not a simple query) and the theater database: Report the average ticket price for tickets sold to the movie "STATE OF THE UNION.”

I have a database ticket_price has the PK as Ticket_type
and movie has a PK of movie_ID

here is my code

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
V_MOVIE_TITLE
MOVIE_TITLE.MOVIE%TYPE;
V_AVG_PRICE
PRICE.TICKET_PRICE%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT MOVIE_TITLE INTO V_MOVIE_TITLE 
FROM MOVIE,
(SELECT AVG(PRICE) INTO V_AVG_PRICE FROM TICKET_PRICE)
TICKET_PRICE
WHERE MOVIE_TITLE = 'STATE OF THE UNION';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('MOVIE NAME       AVERAGE PRICE');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('======================================');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' ' || V_MOVIE_TITLE.MOVIE_ID || '        ' || V_AVG_PRICE.TICKET_PRICE);
END;
/
```

the error seems to be with the subquery avg(price)
how do I get this to run properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
V_MOVIE_TITLE
MOVIE_TITLE.MOVIE%TYPE;
V_AVG_PRICE
PRICE.TICKET_PRICE%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT MOVIE_TITLE INTO V_MOVIE_TITLE 
FROM MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_TITLE = 'STATE OF THE UNION';

SELECT AVG(PRICE) INTO V_AVG_PRICE FROM TICKET_PRICE TICKET_PRICE;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('MOVIE NAME       AVERAGE PRICE');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('======================================');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' ' || V_MOVIE_TITLE.MOVIE_ID || '        ' || V_AVG_PRICE.TICKET_PRICE);
END;
/
```

Comment: SELECT MOVIE_TITLE INTO V_MOVIE_TITLE 
FROM MOVIE,
(SELECT AVG(PRICE) INTO V_AVG_PRICE FROM TICKET_PRICE)
TICKET_PRICE
WHERE MOVIE_TITLE = 'STATE OF THE UNION';this is not subquery，relational Query，query results are inconsistent with your claim types

Comment: That answered my question. Thank you